# Create new label on location of mouse position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello I have got this code:

```
private Label newLabel = new Label();
Int32         mouseX;
Int32         mouseY;

private void form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseY = Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouseX = Cursor.Position.X;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int txt = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < txt; i++)
    {
        newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.Location = new Point(mouseY, mouseX);
        newLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
        newLabel.Text = i.ToString();
        newLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        newLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        newLabel.Font = new Font(newLabel.Font.FontFamily.Name, 10);
        newLabel.Font = new Font(newLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        newLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        newLabel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseMove);
        newLabel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseDown);
        this.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    }
}
```

And I try to make it create a label according to where the mouse is, but it seems that it is creating with location within the whole display. I thought that if I assign the coordinates to `form mouse move` it would get coordinates within the form.
May someone help me solve this out please?

Comment: This just isn't going to work, the mouse position will always be very close to the button.  You'll need to consider a very different kind of UI, something similar to drag+drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cursor.Position coordinate is relative to the whole screen. You need a position relative to the upper left of your form. You could simply get that info from the MouseEventArgs passed  to your MouseMove event handler

```
    private void form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseY = e.Location.Y;
        mouseX = e.Location.X;
    }
```

The [MouseEventArgs.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location.aspx) property is (according to MSDN)

> A Point that contains the x- and y- mouse coordinates, in pixels,
>   relative to the upper-left corner of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Steve is correct, and in order to convert screen coordinates to control or form coordinates you can use method described here:

[How to convert screen coordinates to form relative coordinates (winforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005789/how-to-convert-screen-coordinates-to-form-relative-coordinates-winforms)

In your case:

```
Point clientPoint = PointToClient( new Point( e.X, e.Y ) );
```