# My program will not call the code that is to be executed in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

My code will not make use of the `tmrMoving`(Timer) at all even though the Timer is constantly on with an interval value of 100 so there is no reason  I can see but I'm hoping it's just one of those days and it is simple. The code is as follows,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace games1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tmrMoving.Enabled = true;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture, EventArgs e)
    {

        var cursPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        var playerPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);
        var diff = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - playerPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - playerPoint.Y);
        var speed = Math.Sqrt(diff.X * diff.X + diff.Y * diff.Y);
        if (speed > 10)
        {
            diff.X /= (int)(speed / 10);
            diff.Y /= (int)(speed / 10);
        }
        player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(player.Location.X + diff.X, player.Location.Y + diff.Y);
    }
  }
}
```

This link is to my [coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvI3L.jpg) in an image format if you prefer it that way.

Comment: What is Your Question ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant lines in the code behind?

Comment: I've never seen a timer event handler with so many arguments - is this a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: Did you assign the event handler?

Comment: @MajkeloDev I am curious on your methods for why I cannot get any functionality from my code.

Comment: "I cannot get any functionality" What does it mean ?

Comment: @MajekloDev The coding does not perform any actions and events are not undergone in the program.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Going through the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you have two problems:

1. Your event handler signature doesn't match against [what I expected it to be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I expected it to be:

   ```
   private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   ```
2. Is isn't possible to compile with that broken event handler attached to the event. Therefore it seems to me it isn't assigned at all. Check for the existence of code doing this (probably in the `Designer.cs` file):

   ```
   this.tmrMoving.Tick += tmrMoving_Tick;
   ```

Comment: That may be it actually as it is not in the code. I do not understand why this has not been automatically inputted though...I have never added a Timer into the Designer file any information on location it is needed?

Comment: Just double click on the timer in the designer. it will create an event handler for you and register it properly.

Comment: Hey what would the overload be for a timer? No experience with these?

Comment: Overload? What do you mean?

Comment: Error 1 No overload for 'tmrMoving_Tick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Did you follow point 1?

Comment: I did but mis-clicked and left an expression in, sorry about that.

Comment: I actually have movement now but it is ridiculously far south east of the cursor?

Comment: Your logic might be broken. Use the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: The speed is perfect but and the flow is great but I just cant find the reason why it is so far from the object? [example](http://imgur.com/Z9I116a)

Comment: OOOOhhhh is it because the Cursor isn't relative to only the form? If I put the project at the top of monitor the distance between the cursor and player decreases substantially.

Comment: That can be right indeed.

Comment: So to fix this do I need to make a new question? ^.^ I don't know much to do with this stuff; it's what I'm currently learning. I have a very limited knowledge of C# syntax and compiling orders..

Comment: You have to get your calculations straight. You have to debug and test. Not much I can do without specs.

Comment: The calculations? Since we are using the cursor point it will always be relative to the cursor's position to the **monitor** which means the Position either needs a way to get around this. I think I could do this either by adding an extra variable to determining the player's position such as a percentage of the monitor's screen. On the other hand I may have to alter the cursor's position to only relate to the form's size. I believe this is a viable option but they could both go the wrong way...

Comment: Hmm, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1005789/993547) might be useful in your case. @AshleyFayers